# How to get full current URL with query string Rails-2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails-2.3.10 application. I need to have current full URL with query string .

http://example.come?s=2&t=1&m=3

I know that **request.url** will return full url but without query string.

To get the query string,  I can use **request.query_string**. and finally merge these two results and make it a complete full URL .

I just want to make sure whether its a good approach or Is there any other good approach is out there ? ... Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
`request.request_uri()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Rails 2     request.request_uri()
Rails 3.1   request.url 
Rails 3     request.fullpath()
```